# Java Swing: what class can be used to implement this?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

What Swing class can I use to implement something like this?

[Add To List http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/3260/swingwidget.jpg](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/3260/swingwidget.jpg)

**EDIT:** Hmm..for some reason I cannot add the image here. Well, here's the [link](http://picasaweb.google.com/aristopac23/WhatSwingClassToImplementThis#5400033082379970642):

Basically, I need a list table, where each column can be of different type of gui (i.e. plain text, check box, or drop-down menu).

**EDIT** I have re-publish the image for you ;)

Comment: if someone tries clicking "edit" on my post, you will see I try to add an image to this post. How come I was not able to do it?

Comment: It looks like the picasaweb redirect a number of times the request or something like that. I have re-publised your image in other hosting service. I hope you don't mind

Comment: oh definitely not. thanks for doign that now. now i know it was because of picasa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use a [JTable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to implement it.  Your data will be stored in a TableModel.  The DefaultTableCellRenderer and DefaultTableCellEditor should do what you need, but you can also customize the rendering/behavior if necessary.

More info on renderers/editors: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

Comment: Thanks. The link in your post is perfect for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely [JTable](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

[JTable](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) allow you to define what render will have each column. That way you can add checkboxes, combos, textfields etc. to it.

Here's an screenshot:

[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9430/jtable.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9430/jtable.png)

You can read more about it here: [How to use Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

JTable will do this for you, you're going to need to understand the MVC pattern pretty well to acheive this as you will need a custom model and renderer, but once you get the hang of it its not too hard.

David gearys book "Graphic Java Vol.2" has an excellent section on JTable, whilst this book is now fairly old I still personally think thats the best explanation of JTable I've seen.